# CKeditor not showing for authorized users

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

Drupal 8.5.3, all modules and themes up to date.

The CKEditor only shows up for *administrator* users when creating or editing nodes. The *authorized* users are listed as Roles for the Text Format "Basic HTML" which is the Text Format for the field in the Content Type too.

There is a javascript error being thrown in /core/modules/ckeditor/js/cheditor.js, line 134 saying "drupalSettings.ckeditor" is undefined.

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed!

Turns out it was a problem (errant quote) in html.html.twig that was breaking document.querySelector in drupalSettingsLoader.js so *nothing* in drupalSettings was defined...

Answer (score 0):

it would be helpful if you could share a screenshot.
However, if you have not yet done so, verify that the CKEditor's permissions are enabled for that role and be sure to also verify the permissions of the directory where the module is located.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The module's directory permissions are the same as all the other modules in core.

There's nothing in /admin/people/permissions that I can see that's related to the CKEditor.

But, yes, /admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html has the user role in question checked.

What screenshot can I post that would help?